# Change partition and / or mounting CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, mount, partition

I never did it before, please keep that in mind if I ask a beginner question now, but the info I've found on the internet weren't really useful for my case.

**df -h**

```
    Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
______________________________________________________________________
    /dev/mapper/vg_server01-lv_root
                                      50G   50G     0 100% /
    tmpfs                            127G   12K  127G   1% /dev/shm
    /dev/cciss/c0d0p1                485M   98M  363M  22% /boot
    /dev/mapper/vg_server01-lv_home
                                     754G  197M  716G   1% /home
```

To be honest, I don't understand much what I see, except that the "root" partition seems to be the primary partition and that this partition is full now.

My question is now, what to do? The actual partitions are coming from the automatic CentOS setup. All I want, is to have more space for the main partition, but I don't know how to get it AND I don't know if I need two different partitions ("root" and "home") at all?

Is it possible, to change? What went wrong in my case, so the primary partitions seems to be that small? What do you recommend, how to change?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a hardware-RAID then you can do this without having to re-format the drives, you can do this by booting into rescue mode on CentOS and running the [fdisk](http://geekpeek.net/linux-partitioning-with-fdisk/) command, this'll bring up your current mounting points and filesystems. From that you can use [parted](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-disk-storage-parted-resize-part.html) to resize any partitions on the drive, however I will give word of warning if you choose to do this, it can result in some file corruption and you should always make a full backup of your system.

If your machine doesn't allow this (if it's not in a hard-RAID configuration) you will more than likely need to take a full backup of your files, and re-install the OS from scratch, changing your partition size from the installation directly.

Regarding @Janne's answer before, 50GB is good for the `/` directory if your main files are going to be located on the `/home` directory, but when you're running things on `/var/www` or on SQL then 50GB won't nearly be enough space, especially when you have ~750GB on your `/home` drive that's not being used.

Parted example:

```
(parted) select  /dev/mapper/vg_server01-lv_home
(parted) print
Disk geometry for /dev/hda: 0.000-2445.679 megabytes
Disk label type: msdos
Minor    Start         End     Type      Filesystem  Flags
1          0.031    945.000  primary      FAT         boot, lba
2        945.000   2358.562  primary      ext2
3       2358.562   2445.187  primary   linux-swap
```

A reference from GNU of how to use the (parted) resize:

> Resizes the partition with number minor. The partition will start
>   start from the beginning of the disk, and end end from the beginning
>   of the disk. resize never changes the minor number. Extended
>   partitions can be resized, so long as the new extended partition
>   completely contains all logical partitions.
>
> Note that Parted does not require a file system to be "defragged"
>   (Parted can safely move data around if necessary). It's a waste of
>   time defragging. Don't bother!
>
> Supported file systems:
>
> ext2, ext3 - restriction: the new start must be the same as the old
>   start. fat16, fat32 linux-swap reiserfs (if libreiserfs is installed)
>
> Example:
>
> (parted) resize 3 200 850
>
> Resize partition 3, so that it begins 200
>   megabytes and ends 850 megabytes from the beginning of the disk.

Comment: Given the df output, /home doesn't have anything in it.  You can probably just remove /home completely (parted or fdisk), and extend the lv_root lv using lvextend.  Just make sure to create your home directory in the left over /home.

Comment: It's not very good practice to completely remove the /home directory. If you have ~750GB to play around with, it's good to maybe allocate 20-30GB to /home, just in the off chance that you install something that runs through that directory. Last thing you want is 6-month's down the line to have the exact same problem but this time in reverse, where /home doesn't have enough space and you have to re-format again. Plan ahead.

Comment: Yes, keeping it is fine, however, if he has everything allocated to / to begin with (not separating out /var or /usr or anything), how is keeping /home in with it any different?  Still, he can create a new /home of 10g or something and mount it in place.  Obviously this isn't an enterprise system, or it would have been allocated differently.  I was just giving the easiest option given his apparent circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

For a typical root (`/`) partition 50 GB is plenty. A typical CentOS server installation takes anything between couple of hundreds of megabytes to perhaps 2 GB, a desktop installation can take couple of gigabytes more, depending on what gets installed.

So I suspect your server has huge logs under `/var/log` directory or some program having big data files such as MySQL installed (check `/var/lib/mysql`).

To get a list of 20 biggest directories try this:

```
du -xsm / | sort -nr | head -n 20
```

Comment: du: mount point `/var/named/chroot/var/named' already traversed
50201   /

Comment: It's a fresh CentOS installation and I just copied the files from the old server to this new one via ssh, until I received the message that there is no space left anymore.